# Exception while appending to an existing file in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, append, hdfs

I'm basically trying to append data to an already exisiting file in HDFS. This is the exception I get

```
03:49:54,456WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run:628 DataStreamer Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.checkForNullValues(AbstractMessageLite.java:336)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder.addAll(AbstractMessageLite.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$UpdatePipelineRequestProto$Builder.addAllStorageIDs(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.updatePipeline(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:842)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:532)
```

My replication factor is 1. I'm using 2.5.0 of Apache's Hadoop  distribution. This is the code snippet which I'm using for creating a file if it doesn't exist or create in append mode if it exists

```
String url = getHadoopUrl()+fileName;
    Path file = new Path(url);
    try {
        if(append) {
            if(hadoopFileSystem.exists(file))
                fsDataOutputStream = hadoopFileSystem.append(file);
            else
                fsDataOutputStream = hadoopFileSystem.create(file);
        }
        else
            fsDataOutputStream = hadoopFileSystem.create(file);
```

It's not quite clear what is causing this exception. Also I'm quite confused after reading various sources whether appending is supported in HDFS or not. Let me know what I'm missing here

EDIT: Appending stack trace that I found in datanode's log

```
 2015-10-30 16:19:54,435 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-1012136337-192.168.123.103-1411103100884:blk_1073742239_1421 src: /127.0.0.1:54160  dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
 2015-10-30 16:19:54,435 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Appending to FinalizedReplica, blk_1073742239_1421, FINALIZED
 getNumBytes()     = 812
 getBytesOnDisk()  = 812
 getVisibleLength()= 812
 getVolume()       = /Users/niranjan/hadoop/hdfs/datanode/current
 getBlockFile()    = /Users/niranjan/hadoop/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-        1012136337-192.168.123.103-1411103100884/current/finalized/blk_1073742239
 unlinked          =false
2015-10-30 16:19:54,461 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception for BP-1012136337-192.168.123.103-1411103100884:blk_1073742239_1422
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF from inputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you please show the whole stack trace ?

Comment: That is the stack trace I get in my application's log. I'm appending a stack trace which I found in datanode's log in the question, maybe that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem in Hadoop from version 2.2.0 to 2.5.1, upgrading to an higher version resolved this without any tweak in the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

By searching I find adding the following to your `hdfs-site.xml` may help.

```
<property> 
<name>dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads</name> 
<value>8192</value> 
</property>
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem